# trigger after update invalidating existing update script

Tags: php, mysql

.I have a manually executed script that works successfully to insert a record into a database on a different server

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO job (JID, FID, crtd,) 
  VALUES ('$jid', '$fm', '$crt')";
```

I have an trigger that works successfully when I insert a record into the Job table via phpmyadmin

```
  BEGIN
INSERT INTO pix SET JID = NEW.JID;
INSERT INTO cae SET JID = NEW.JID;
INSERT INTO checklist SET JID = NEW.JID;
INSERT INTO awgform SET JID = NEW.JID;
END
```

However the moment I put the trigger in,.... the original script to create the record fails, is this a question of privilege?

Comment: the moment I put the trigger in the original script to create the record fails - I am unclear what you mean by this you cannot execute a trigger.

Comment: However the moment I put the trigger in,.... the original manual script to create the record fails, is this a question of privilege?     missed some punctuation

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: I just get the error message that my insert script failed.
basically it works until I put the trigger in.
the trigger works when I am logged on to phpmyadmin, and I update the job table.